# Facebook drop down menu goes behind embeded you tube video fan page

Tags: youtube, facebook-page

I am currently having some trouble displaying a you tube video on my custom fan page. I am using Static HTML I Frame Tab to embed this code. The problem is that the facebook notifications or search drop down menu continues to go behind y you tube video when using IE.

I have included param name="wmode" value="transparent" within the embeded you tube code but for whatever reason the fb drop down menu continues to go behind the video. The fan page is https://www.facebook.com/blaineostrander

Again, this issue only seems to be happening in IE

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your issue - but if you are dealing with flash inside Facebook you should defiantly look at this : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/637/

Comment: Thank you.. I think I figured it out. I needed to add a attribute wmode="transparent" on the embed tag

Answer (score 1):

Into src in iframe put **?wmode=opaque**

Ex :

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" 
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/pVllEZirODQ?wmode=opaque" 
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Works great for me